# Getting 500 server not found in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting 500 server not found in my laravel 5.4 application.

I tried some solutions like permissions of files and so on.
But unfortunately not got the proper solution.

Please suggest me the right way.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at what is MCVE at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the very common question.
You can check the file permission of your folder structure as below:

- All folders and files in your laravel directory structure give **755** permission (sudo chmod -R 755 laravel_app)
- After that assign **777** permission to the **storage** folder (sudo chmod -R 777 laravel_app/storage)
- After that restart the web server

I hope it will solve your problem.

If still, you are facing 500 Interna Server Error then try below steps:

- Delete laravel log file from storage/logs folder (rm -rf storage/logs/laravel.logs)
- Clear artisan cache (php artisan cache:clear)
- Composer dump autoload (php artisan composer dump-autoload)

I hope, it will help you.